# Getting errors when trying to tail or do port-forward

Tags: debugging, logging, ssh, openshift, portforwarding

I am able to ssh to my machine and I also did rhc setup. But when trying to use the rhc tail and rhc portforward I am getting the following errors:

```
> rhc tail <GEAR_NAME>
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
You can tail this application directly with:
ssh -t 52eeb24b500446f59000012e@<MY_APP>.rhcloud.com 'tail */log*/*'
.../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:81:in `negotiate!': unknown
response from agent: 1, "\x00\x00\x00,\x01\x00\x00\x00'SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.7.0 x64-mingw32" (Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError)
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:48:in `connect'

        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:178:in `agent'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:102:in `each_ide
ntity'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `aut
henticate'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:78:in `block in auth
enticate'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:65:in `each'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:65:in `authenticate'

        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:204:in `start'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:172:in `ssh_ruby'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands/tail.rb:40:in `tail'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands/tail.rb:21:in `run'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `execute'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands.rb:276:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'

        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:73:in `run!'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'

> rhc port-forward <GEAR_NAME>
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Checking available ports ... .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb
:81:in `negotiate!': unknown response from agent: 1, "\x00\x00\x00,\x01\x00\x00\x00'SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.7.0 x64-mingw32" (Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError)
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:48:in `connect'

        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:178:in `agent'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:102:in `each_ide
ntity'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `aut
henticate'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:78:in `block in auth
enticate'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:65:in `each'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:65:in `authenticate'

        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:204:in `start'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands/port_forward.rb:85:in `run'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `execute'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/commands.rb:276:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'

        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:73:in `run!'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rhc-1.19.5/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from .../Ruby200-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably answer your question, https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1080-why-all-rhc-commands-on-windows-result-in-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle-error.

The bug is closed but I think it may need be to reopened if you're still hitting this issue. Try updating rhc first and then give it another try.

Comment: >gem update rhc = 
Nothing to update.

Per the logs my version is 1.19.5